# Identify user from access token in custom rest API

Tags: apex, rest-api

In my custom rest resource, I want to identify the user who made the API call. Since API call includes Authorization header with access token, can I get the user from this value?

Answer (score 5):

Just use the [`UserInfo`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) class, which:

> Contains methods for obtaining information about the context user.

Specifically, you can get their `Id`, `Name`, `Username`, etc.

```
Id runningUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
String runningUserName = UserInfo.getName();
String runningUserUsername = UserInfo.getUsername();
```

Comment: Thanks Andrian, I posted the question without trying it. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

It works just like controllers.

`UserInfo.getuserId()` does the job